# Sort recorded in 2016 generates "Error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method" in 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro for a 2 column sort, that works, on Excel 2016.

I get the following error on Excel 2010.

> Error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method.

What is not acceptable for the 2010 version of Excel?

```
Sub SortOpenOrder()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("Table2[[#Headers],[Customer No.]]").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Open Orders").ListObjects("Table2").Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Open Orders").ListObjects("Table2").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add2 Key:=Range("Table2[Customer No.]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Open Orders").ListObjects("Table2").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add2 Key:=Range("Table2[PO '#]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Open Orders").ListObjects("Table2").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("Table2[[#Headers],[Customer No.]]").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: On what line does the error occur? It might be because of an incompatibility between versions. Keep in mind that recorded macros are a resource mostly used when learning VBA and its syntax. In order to reuse your code, it's best to refactor it.

Comment: If fails here;    `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Open Orders").ListObjects("Table2").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add2 Key:=Range("Table2[Customer No.]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal`

Answer (score 2):

The code you have doesn't look like it would bomb on either version of Excel, but refactoring it for better coding practices will surely help (as fabio alluded to).

Try this:

```
Dim myTable as ListObject
Set myTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Open Orders").ListObjects("Table2")

With myTable.Sort

    With .SortFields
         .Clear
         .Add Key:=myTable.ListColumns("Customer No.").DataBodyRange, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
         .Add Key:=myTable.ListColumns("PO '#").DataBodyRange, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With

   .Header = xlYes
   .MatchCase = False
   .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
   .SortMethod = xlPinYin
   .Apply

End With
```

Comment: @WadeProudlock - on what line? I suspect it may be the lines that define the sort range. Try this instead: `myTable.ListColumns("Customer No.").DataBodyRange` or you may need to reference the entire range including header.

Comment: You were right. This is now working with the `.DataBodyRange` edit.

`.Add Key:=myTable.ListColumns("Customer No.").DataBodyRange, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
.Add Key:=myTable.ListColumns("PO #").DataBodyRange, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal`

Thank you so much for your help!